# Generating 1s and -1s in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random

How do you generate a random vector consisting of  only 1 and -1 in MATLAB? I am looking for a function that generates a vector of random integers drawn from a set, not necessarily 1:N.

Comment: Generate integers from 0 to 1, multiply by 2 and subtract 1. `0*2-1 = -1`; `1*2-1 = 1`.

Comment: Which one is it? 1 and -1 or some selection?

Comment: Ok for only 1 and -1, multiplying by 2 and subtracting 1 works. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `S` is the set of values you want to draw randomly from, and you want to generate `n` values, you can do:

```
S = [-1,1];
n = 20;
M = S(randi(numel(S),n,1));
```

This returns:

```
M = [-1 -1 -1 1 1 1 -1 1 1 1 -1 1 1 -1 1 -1 1 1 1 1]
```

`randi` generates random integers in the range [`1`,`numel(S)`], which is equivalent to random indices into the array `S`. You use these indices to index into `S` to obtain the values.

This works for any `S`:

```
S = 2.^[0:10];
M = S(randi(numel(S),1,10));
```

returns:

```
M = [2 256 1 8 8 1 1 2 1024 16]
```